# How to add an view between two others inside an Relative Layout container?

Tags: android

I have a `RelativeLayout` container with child views, like this:

```
[ -> begin of relative layout containner
 [view] -> view (LinearLayout)
 [view] -> view (LinearLayout) + rule (below of previous view)
 [view] -> view (LinearLayout) + rule (below of previous view)
] -> end of relative layout
```

Everything is being generated programmatically.

After the event, I need to add a child between two child views. I make this:

```
public void add(PerguntaViewContainner parent, PerguntaViewContainner child) {
    PerguntaViewContainner previousChild = parent;
    PerguntaViewContainner nextChild =  HocusPocus.getNextElementOf(parent);

    perguntaParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, previousChild.getId());
    perguntaParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, nextChild.getId());

    containner.addView(child, perguntaParams);
}
```

But the child is not showing up. Do You have any idea, why it could happen?

Comment: What are PerguntaViewContainner and PerguntaViewContainner ? How are they related to RelativeLayout and LinearLayout and why they are not provide in the 'diagram' with views structure?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like You might need to correct other child params also, like the following:

```
public void add(PerguntaViewContainner parent, PerguntaViewContainner child) {
    PerguntaViewContainner previousChild = parent;
    PerguntaViewContainner nextChild =  HocusPocus.getNextElementOf(parent);

    perguntaParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, previousChild.getId());
    perguntaParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, nextChild.getId());

    containner.addView(child, perguntaParams);

    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams nextViewParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)nextChild.getLayoutParams();

    nextViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, child.getId())
    nextChild.setLayoutParams(nextViewParams);
}
```

However, the question is not complete and it easily can be any issue with your custom layouts.